# ASP.Net MVC3 webapplication directory structure

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, project, structure

I am moving our current ASP.net website to a MVC3 project and am very new to MVC. Currently we have a 2 level authorization for a superadmin and a admin. Both these levels of authorization get directed to a menu where there are some common and some different pages which they each access. I was wondering how I could structure it such that there will be minimum duplication of controller logic with URLs like -

myURL/SuperAdmin
myURL/SuperAdmin/Users
myURL/SuperAdmin/Users/UserId

Similarly for Admin.

For the above kind of URL I may have to duplicate the controller code (for the Users view) in the SuperAdmin as well as the Admin controllers. As both these access the Users View. I would like to avoid this, but have the same URL. We are making use of the existing business layer entity framework (stored procedures) and not using any LinqToSql. Can I use named routing for this? If so, how? I hope I am making myself clear.
Can someone please help? Any ideas and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
sdd

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on this. If you think you will have code duplication then remove that code into common classes that multiple controllers will access. Sure you can have multiple routes point you to the same controller/action methods (if thats what you meant) but I recommend you don't have multiple URI's (excluding varying parameters) that go into the same controller method. It makes your app a bit hard to follow.